# C++ Sorting array that is a pointer to a class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, sorting, pointers

I am trying to sort an array of cars which have prices in them, I seem to be having a problem sorting the array that is a pointer to another class. I get "error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value" when I try to change the order of the array.

I have attached the code below.

My sort function.

```
void CarPool::Sort()
{
    const int MAXVAL = 9;
    int coun = countCars;
    double temp;
    bool swappedFlag = true;

    while (swappedFlag)
    {
        swappedFlag = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < countCars - 1; i++)
        {
            ptrToPool[i].getPrice();
            if (ptrToPool[i].getPrice()> ptrToPool[i + 1].getPrice())
            {
                temp = ptrToPool[i].getPrice();
                ptrToPool[i].getPrice() = ptrToPool[i + 1].getPrice(); //ERROR C2106
                ptrToPool[i + 1].getPrice() = temp; //ERROR C2106
                swappedFlag = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

car.cpp

```
#pragma once
#include "car.h"  // put the related header at the TOP of the list of   includes
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

Car::Car(string mName, string reg, double eng, double pri)
{
    // store the parameter values for this object private data
     ModelName = mName;
     Registration = reg;
     EngineSize = eng;
     Price = pri;
}

Car::Car()
{
// set up a value that shows the data not properly loaded
    ModelName = "Unspecified";
}

void Car::Load(ifstream& carFile)
{
    carFile>>ModelName>>Registration>>EngineSize>>Price;

}


void Car::Display()
{
    cout<<setfill(' ')<<setw(10)<<ModelName<<setfill(' ')<<setw(10)<<Registration;
    cout<<setfill(' ')<<setw(10)<<EngineSize<<setfill(' ')<<setw(10)<<Price<<endl;
}

double Car::Ratio() //how much it costs per cc of engine!
{
    return EngineSize/Price;
}

string Car::getRegistration()
{
    return Registration;
}

double Car::getPrice()
{
    return Price;
}
```

carpool.cpp (also the function listed in the first piece of code)

```
#include "carpool.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

CarPool::CarPool()
{
    countCars=0; //for now
    name = "None";
}

CarPool::~CarPool()
{
    if (countCars>0)
    {
        delete [] ptrToPool;
    }
}

int CarPool::Load(string fromFilename)
{
    // assumes file starts with count of cars
    ifstream inFile(fromFilename);
    if (!inFile)
    {
        return -1; //oh dear no file to read
    }
    inFile>>countCars; //read the following number of cars
    ptrToPool = new Car[countCars];
    for (int i=0; i<countCars; i++)
    {
        ptrToPool[i].Load(inFile);
    }
    return 0; //successful!
}
```

car.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Car
{
public:
    // see later for the bodies of the functions!
    Car(string mName, string reg, double eng, double pri);
    Car();
    void Load(ifstream& carFile);
    void Save(ofstream& carFile);
    void Display();
    string getRegistration();
    double getPrice();
    double Ratio(); //how much it costs per cc of engine!
    void setPrice(double pri);

private:
    string ModelName;
    string Registration;
    double EngineSize;
    double Price;
};
```

Comment: You need to swap the cars themselves, not the values. "ptrToPool[i]= ptrToPool[i + 1];" etc. In addition I would highly recommend using more standard library functions. In particular, std::sort would do most of the job for you. You could also use std::swap for the swap. You could also use std::vector instead of an array. When you use standard library functions, your code tends to be simpler, faster, and more bug-free.

Answer (score 0):

`getPrice()` in defined to return a double:

```
double Car::getPrice()
```

Now, in the following statements you get ERROR C2106 since you're trying to make an assignment a number (vs. a variable):

```
ptrToPool[i].getPrice() = ptrToPool[i + 1].getPrice(); //ERROR C2106
ptrToPool[i + 1].getPrice() = temp; //ERROR C2106
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `std::swap` (on the car objects) where you get the error (you need the `move` assignment and constructor to be defined).

The standard library implemented it for you - now go use it.

PS: You are getting the error because your getter function returns a value rather than a reference (to which you could assign a value).

If you don't want to use the Standard Library you could let the getter method return a reference or you could use a setter function on the left side of the `=`.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**
Given the class implementation, you cannot set the price using getPrice() since it is just a getter not a setter. Therefore the lines:

```
ptrToPool[i].getPrice() = ptrToPool[i + 1].getPrice(); //ERROR C2106
ptrToPool[i + 1].getPrice() = temp; //ERROR C2106
```

are expected to give error about the left hand side of the equation.

**Solution:**
You need a setter. Something like:

```
ptrToPool[i].setPrice(someValue);
```

**Sample Implementation:**
Try adding the following method to your class:

```
void Car::setPrice(double pri)
{
    Price=pri;
}
```

Then call this method to update prices as follows (replace your two lines with those):

```
ptrToPool[i].setPrice(ptrToPool[i + 1].getPrice());
ptrToPool[i + 1].getPrice(temp);
```

**Additional:**
Although this will solve your current issue on error messages, you still need to revise your sorting algorithm.

1. Do you want to sort the cars or just prices? FYI: Swapping the prices will not affect the other data!
2. What kind of sorting algorithm are you trying to implement? Insertion Sort or Selection sort? Please recall that they are O(nxn). You may use library sort (i.e., std::sort) which is "quick sort" and has O(nxlogn) time complexity so much faster for large data. You may refer to:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/?kw=sort

**EDIT ON SORTING:**

For sorting the cars in increasing order of prices you could do the following:

First, include the following for using the library sort:

```
#include <algorithm>
```

Second, add a less than (<) operator overload to your car class based on price. (Edit: As n0rd suggested instead of operator overloading you may define a custom comparator for more generic approach. There is an example how to do in the above link.) 
You final class will look like:

```
class Car
{
public:
    // see later for the bodies of the functions!
    Car(string mName, string reg, double eng, double pri);
    Car();
    void Load(ifstream& carFile);
    void Save(ofstream& carFile);
    void Display();
    string getRegistration();
    double getPrice();
    double Ratio(); //how much it costs per cc of engine!
    void setPrice(double pri);
    bool operator < (const Car& car) const
    {
        return (Price < car.Price);
    }

private:
    string ModelName;
    string Registration;
    double EngineSize;
    double Price;
};
```

Finally in your sort function just call:

```
std::sort(ptrToPool, ptrToPool + size);
```

Therefore your final sort function will be the following (Yes that short!):

```
void CarPool::Sort()
{
    std::sort(ptrToPool, ptrToPool + countCars);
}
```

Just replace this function with your sort function and it should sort the cars based on their price in increasing order.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I still not sure how I would sort the cars and not just the prices. Do I have to create a setter method for all the data members? @erol yeniaras

Comment: @BeginnerLK: Because your question was "sort an array of cars which have prices in them". Therefore I am assuming that you want to sort the cars based on their prices. Don`t you?

Comment: @BeginnerLK: You have to create setter method for every private data members that you want to individually modify outside the class implamantation. Here again, I am assuming that ModelName, Registration,    EngineSize and Price are all private data members of your class in your car.h file and the class does not have an inheritance relation with any other class.

Comment: @BeginnerLK: If you don`t mind could you put the definition of your car class (car.h I suppose) on your question?

Comment: I have added car.h as part of the question. I now understand much better how classes work. Thank You. @erol yeniaras

Comment: @BeginnerLK: Your class definition looks pretty good. If you haven`t changed you sort function yet, you still compare and swap the prices. Instead, you may want to compare the prices but swap the cars. Let me know if you need information about the sorting algorithms as well.

Comment: Yes that would be useful. @erol yeniaras

Comment: @BeginnerLK: Please look at my answer starting from the subtitle: EDIT ON SORTING.

Comment: I'd suggest passing a custom comparator to `std::sort` instead of overloading `operator <` for `Car` class as generally this overload does not make much sense for `Car` class outside of sorting-by-price context.

Comment: @n0rd: I agree with you. Custom comparator would have been more flexible than the operator overload especially when using criteria other than the "Price" for sorting. Please note that, in the original link that I included: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/?kw=sort there is such an example. Therefore, I have defined the operator overload as an alternative quick approach for this specific question. Thanks for your note!

Comment: @n0rd: Edited the answer including your suggestion!